# Need help trying to use @property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, getter-setter

New to Objective-C (and programming for that matter), so please don't be too harsh if this question is very basic.

Apart from my **main.m** class, I have a **Student.h** and **Student.m** class, which I created. I am trying to avoid using many getters and setters for future projects, and if I'm correct, **@property** can help me with that. My basic code that works is this:

**Student.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Student : NSObject{

NSString *name;
int age;

}

//setters
- (void)setName:(NSString*)fName;
- (void)setAge:(int)newAge;

//getters
- (NSString*)getName;
- (int)getAge;


@end
```

**Student.m:**

```
#import "Student.h"

@implementation Student

- (void)setName:(NSString*)fName {

   name = fName;

}

- (void)setAge:(int)newAge {

   age = newAge;

}

- (NSString*)getName {

   return name;
}


- (int)getAge {

   return age;
}


@end
```

Can I use @property to have something like this, which would avoid using getter and setter methods? Or do I understand it all wrong?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Student : NSObject{


}

@property int age;
@property NSString *name;


@end
```

Comment: your properties are good

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. In Objective C you don't use get prefix for getters. You should use either plain name or with 'is' prefix for boolean properties. ([Objective C conventions reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html))
2. You really won't avoid using getters and setters. `@property` notation just defines them for you (maybe with some additional behaviors like copying the value instead of assigning it). It's just the matter of `.` notation. Underneath it's using getter/setter methods. Here you have a bit more on properties ([Objetive C properties reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW3)).
3. You should define your `NSString` property as `(copy)`. It's much better to have as if you change it somewhere else it will affect this object (and probably you want to avoid that).

Answer (score 0):

Are you coming from Java perhaps?

Yes, Objective-C used to require getters and setters to be written out laboriously by hand. Nowadays if you use `@property` and don't go out of your way to do anything else then a suitable instance variable and an appropriate getter and setter will be generate for you.

So the following is a complete class with usable properties, accessible either via traditional `setName:`/`name`-style setters and getters or via the dot notation (which calls the setters and getters despite looking like a C struct access:

```
@interface Student : NSObject

@property int age;
@property NSString *name;

@end

/* ... */

@implementation Student
@end
```

Also as a general encapsulation / data-hiding comment, notice that Objective-C has long ago been modified so that instance variables can be declared in the [unpublished] `@implementation` rather than the [published] `@interface`. On a technical level it was all to do with the ABI and the fragile base class problem, neither of which haunts the modern runtime.